# should aspx and html page be integrated in a single project?

Tags: html, asp.net, web

I'm working on a web app and want to know whether integrating aspx pages and html pages should be used simultaneously?

Is it just to decrease or reduce laoding time of some static pages in the web app?

Comment: "Is it just to decrease or reduce laoding time of some static pages in the web app?" basically, yes, that's a big reason. if your aspx pages are not too big it's not a big concern.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
 you can integrate .html & .aspx files into your single project web application.

Comment: i nkow it can be done...i just need to know whether it should be done or not ? or in other words is it a good practice of doing so ?

Comment: @Rajan It's depend on the your requirement.  Html is always take less time in loading then aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

When you develop a website in ASP.NET , the intent is more concentrated towards building a **dynamic Website**. Thought you can build static pages too with the same, but it totally depends on your discretion whether you want to build the static pages with `.html` extension or `aspx`. My suggestion would be to carry out the same extension so that the website looks well architectured

**Note:**  *Currently search engines don't rank based on extension. So you have the freedom to chose as per your like*